# why my useReducer function is not working.when I use it The page show but function is not working

Tags: reactjs, reduce

> Hello Everyone . I'm New in react .Every thing is okay But when I'm start using Reducer. It's Not working properly. It's Adding function or deleting function is not working. Why This problem. before using reducer I'm working with context api . and the same project I want work with reducer. but it's not working properly. The page is show but It's Add or remove function is not working

**BookContext.jsx**

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer, useEffect } from 'react';
// import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid' // This is update vertion 
import { bookReducer } from '../BookReducer/Reducer';

export const BookContext = createContext();

const BookContextProvider = (props) => {
    const [books, dispatch] = useReducer(bookReducer, []);
    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem('books', JSON.stringify(books))
    }, [books])


    return (
        <div>
            <BookContext.Provider value={{ books, dispatch }}>
                {props.children}
            </BookContext.Provider>
        </div>
    );
};

export default BookContextProvider;
```

**Reducer.jsx**

```
    import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid' // This is update vertion 

export const bookReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ' ADD_BOOK':
            return [...state, {
                title: action.book.title,
                author: action.book.author,
                id: uuid()
            }]
        case 'REMOVE_BOOK':
            return state.filter(book => book.id !== action.id)

        default:
            return state;
    }

}
```

**BookForm.jsx**

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react';
import { BookContext } from '../Context/BookContext';

const NewBookform = () => {
    const { dispatch } = useContext(BookContext);
    const [title, setitle] = useState('');
    const [author, setauthor] = useState('');
    const Handelesubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        dispatch({
            type: 'ADD_BOOK', book: {
                title, author
            }
        })
        setitle(' ');
        setauthor(' ');
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={Handelesubmit}>
                <input type='text' placeholder='Book Title' value={title} onChange
                    ={(e) => setitle(e.target.value)} required />
                <br></br>
                <input type='text' placeholder='Book author' value={author} onChange
                    ={(e) => setauthor(e.target.value)} required />

                <br></br>

                <input type='submit' value=" ADD Book" />
            </form>
        </div>
    );
};

export default NewBookform;
```

**Bookdetails**

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { BookContext } from '../Context/BookContext';

const Bookldetails = ({ book }) => {
    const { dispatch } = useContext(BookContext)
    return (
        <li onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'REMOVE_BOOK', id: book.id })}>
            <div className="title">{book.title}</div>
            <div className="id">{book.author}</div>
        </li>
    );
};

export default Bookldetails;
```

Comment: i think u should access dispatch from props not from `useContext(BookContext)`

Answer (score 0):

Your remove function works just fine, here is your code:

```js
const { createContext, useReducer, useContext } = React;
const uuid = ((id) => () => ++id)(0);
const BookContext = createContext();
const bookReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ' ADD_BOOK':
      return [
        ...state,
        {
          title: action.book.title,
          author: action.book.author,
          id: uuid(),
        },
      ];
    case 'REMOVE_BOOK':
      return state.filter((book) => book.id !== action.id);

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const BookContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [books, dispatch] = useReducer(bookReducer, [
    { id: uuid(), title: 'title 1', author: 'author 1' },
    { id: uuid(), title: 'title 2', author: 'author 2' },
  ]);
  //this is not doing anything, you are never reading it
  // useEffect(() => {
  //   localStorage.setItem('books', JSON.stringify(books));
  // }, [books]);

  return (
    <div>
      <BookContext.Provider value={{ books, dispatch }}>
        {props.children}
      </BookContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
};
const Bookldetails = ({ book }) => {
  const { dispatch } = useContext(BookContext);
  return (
    <li
      onClick={() =>
        dispatch({ type: 'REMOVE_BOOK', id: book.id })
      }
    >
      <div className="title">{book.title}</div>
      <div className="id">{book.author}</div>
    </li>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const { books } = useContext(BookContext);
  return (
    <ul>
      {books.map((book) => (
        <Bookldetails key={book.id} book={book} />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <BookContextProvider>
    <App />
  </BookContextProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```